# Error al agregar una FK a una tabla en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Explico mi problema:

Tengo 2 tablas las cuales son "cliente" y "descuentoMembresia" donde descuentoMembresia tiene como PK codigo_descuento, en mi tabla cliente agrego un nuevo campo el cual se llama "codigo_descuento" el cual quiero utilizar para crear mi FK con la tabla "descuentoMembresia", pero al momento que ejecuto el ALTER me aparece error "Cannot add foreign key constraint".

¿como puedo resolver este error?

```
ALTER TABLE cliente ADD CONSTRAINT codigo_descuento FOREIGN KEY (codigo_descuento) REFERENCES descuentoMembresia(codigo_descuento);
```

Comment: Muestra el mensaje de error completo que te arroja. Lo más seguro es que los datos no estén normalizados para el tipo de constraint que quieres agregar. Por ejemplo, si existen registros huérfanos o cosas así, todo eso debe ser normalizado antes.

Comment: tambien recordar que las tablas deben tener "ENGINE=INNODB" para poder crear las FK..

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con los registros para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar el [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]